# HTML Hovering Image Code

Tags: html, css, hover

I have code for when you rollover an image, it enlarges next to it, but when i add another image, it enlarges in the same place, how can i make it so that each image enlarges next to the small original one? this is the code;

```
<div id="imgmenu">
<div class="p1" title="Karla"><img src="small image" title="Thumbnail image" alt="Thumbnail image" / ><img class="large" src="large image" title="enlarged view of image" alt="enlarged view of image" /></div></div>
<style type="text/css"> 
<#imgmenu {position:relative; top:10px; left:10px; width:75px; background-color:#fff; z-index:100;} 
#imgmenu .p1 {display:block; width:150px; height:150px; text-decoration:none; background:#fff; top:0; left:0; border:0;} 
#imgmenu .p1:hover {text-decoration:none; background-color:#8c97a3; color:#000;} 
#imgmenu .large {display:block; position:absolute; width:0; height:0; border:0; top:0; left:0;} 
#imgmenu .p1:hover .large {display:block; position:absolute; top:-0px; left:150px; width:400px; height:300px; border:2px solid #ccc;} 
#info {z-index:100; height:22em;}
</style>  


<div id="imgmenu">
<div class="p1" title="Beanie"><img src="small image" title="Thumbnail image" alt="Thumbnail image" / ><img class="large" src="large image" title="enlarged view of image" alt="enlarged view of image" /></div></div>
<style type="text/css"> 
<#imgmenu {position:relative; top:10px; left:10px; width:75px; background-color:#fff; z-index:100;} 
#imgmenu .p1 {display:block; width:150px; height:150px; text-decoration:none; background:#fff; top:0; left:0; border:0;} 
#imgmenu .p1:hover {text-decoration:none; background-color:#8c97a3; color:#000;} 
#imgmenu .large {display:block; position:absolute; width:0; height:0; border:0; top:0; left:0;} 
#imgmenu .p1:hover .large {display:block; position:absolute; top:-0px; left:150px; width:400px; height:300px; border:2px solid #ccc;} 
#info {z-index:100; height:22em;} 
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your code. When you define an id for an element in your HTML, it must be unique: here, you're using `<div id="imgmenu">` for two elements. Instead use classes. Also, there's no need to define CSS styles twice. Here's a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw8Kf/3/)** where I fixed a few things and here's the HTML:

```
<div class="imgmenu">
<div class="p1" title="Karla">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
    <img class="large" src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="imgmenu">
<div class="p1" title="Beanie">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
    <img class="large" src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
</div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.imgmenu {
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    width:75px;
    background-color:#fff;
    z-index:100;} 

.imgmenu .p1 {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background:#fff;} 

.imgmenu .p1:hover {
    background-color:#8c97a3;
    color:#000;} 

.imgmenu .large {
    position:absolute; width:0; height:0; border:0; top:0; left:0;} 

.imgmenu .p1:hover .large {
    position:absolute;
    left:150px;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    border:2px solid #ccc;}
```

Comment: BTW, I updated the jsfiddle where I removed as much as the superfluous code as possible: http://jsfiddle.net/Lw8Kf/5/